# buffering one feature class by different distance, the result is the buffer distance become same 100 feet

Tags: arcpy, buffer

```
try:
# Import modules
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env
# Set the workspace
    env.workspace = r"C:\Esripresspython\GISTPython\Data\City of Oleander.gdb"
# Create a variable with the name of the subject feature class
    fcName = "StreetLights"
# The buffer distance is dependent on the type of light
# Check to see what type it is
    typeCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcName,["TYPE"])
        for row in typeCursor:
        lightType = row[0]
# TYPE == MV uses a buffer of 125
# TYPE == MVH uses a buffer of 160
# TYPE == SV uses a buffer of 100
# TYPE == SVH uses a buffer of 200
        if lightType == "MV":
            lightBuffDist = 125
        elif lightType == "MVH":
            lightBuffDist = 160
        elif lightType == "SV":
            lightBuffDist = 100
        else:
            lightBuffDist = 200
# perform the buffering
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fcName,r"C:\Esripresspython\GISTPython\Data\City of Oleander.gdb\LightBuffer",lightBuffDist)
    print "Done"
except:
    print "the process did not complete."
```

---

Buffering the street light by different distance, to determine whether there are any areas of town that do not have adequate nightlight illumination.
this program works but the value of buffer_Distance became 100. I was wondering why this situation happened?

Comment: If you join a lookup between your light types and buffer distances into your feature class then you would be able to accomplish this in a single pass of Buffer by naming the field that holds the buffer distances.

Comment: @polyGeo thank you.but i could not understand your suggestion very well. what your means is add a field first and value it for the buffer distance?

Comment: Yes - or if there are hundreds/thousands of them to update just create a small table that has type and distance that you can use the Join Fields tool on to do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue here is that you are iterating through your input feature class with your cursor, and assigning a value to the variable `lightBuffDist`. This variable is being updated for each row in your cursor. Finally, it reaches the final row, which appears to have the value "SV" in the field "TYPE". This assigns 100 to the variable lightBuffDist. Your Buffer_analysis is then performed with 100 as the distance input.

In order to perform your buffer analysis with varying buffer distances, you will need to add a field to your feature class using `AddField_management`, and then populate this field with your desired buffer distance using an `UpdateCursor`.

Try this code:

```
try:
# Import modules
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env
# Set the workspace
    env.workspace = r"C:\Esripresspython\GISTPython\Data\City of Oleander.gdb"
# Create a variable with the name of the subject feature class
    fcName = "StreetLights"
# The buffer distance is dependent on the type of light
# Add Field To record distance
    DistFldName = "BUFF_DIS"
    AddField_management (fcName, DistFldName, "SHORT")
    typeCursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcName,["TYPE", DistFldName])
        for row in typeCursor:
        lightType = row[0]
# TYPE == MV uses a buffer of 125
# TYPE == MVH uses a buffer of 160
# TYPE == SV uses a buffer of 100
# TYPE == SVH uses a buffer of 200
        if lightType == "MV":
            row[1] = 125
        elif lightType == "MVH":
            row[1] = 160
        elif lightType == "SV":
            row[1] = 100
        else:
            row[1] = 200
        typeCursor.updateRow(row)

# perform the buffering
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fcName,r"C:\Esripresspython\GISTPython\Data\City of Oleander.gdb\LightBuffer", DistFldName)
# Optional :Delete field with buffer distance
    arcpy.DeleteField_management (fcName, DistFldName)

    print "Done"
except:
    print "the process did not complete."
```